# Cross in Genetic Algorithms using np.ndarray in python

Tags: python

How do I create a cross-function for a genetic algorithm? I have two pieces of DNA A and B and want to create C by combining the parents randomly. How do I do that using np.ndarray?

Comment: Hi, welcome! What have you tried so far? Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: I don't know where exactly I would start

Comment: That's quite a broad question and not really the point of this website. What results did you get on your search engine? You could start by thinking about using partial selection of an array, for example by ways of `a[1:2]` or `a[-3:]`.